# Network interface goes down randomly but comes back up after reboot

Tags: drivers, network-manager

After installing ubuntu on my new HP Probook, I’ve had problems staying connected to wifi for more than a few minutes.
At first it all works fine, but then I get a notification saying Wireless Interface (wlp2s0) The wifi network could not be found.

When doing lspci -v it says !!! Unknown header type 7f.
The network card is a Realtek 8852BE.

Comment: Check for more info: Opena a terminal and type `dmsg | less` and look for network related things, failures, errors, warnings. dmsg looks in the latest of files in `/var/log/` - you might find more in the other ones, `zcat ...` displays the content of *.gz files.

Comment: It’s saying `rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: write rf busy swsi` and `rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0 read rf busy swsi` over and over.

Comment: Give us more, not just picked details; e.g. What is there just before it starts that repeating thing?

Comment: Right before the repeating thing it says `xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10` `xtal si not ready(W): offset=90 val=10 mask=10’ `mac init fail, ret:-110` `failed to leave idle state` `FW does not process h2c registers`

Comment: Well, based on that limited detail I'd say yuo have a hardware problem (may be heat related), the simple solution might be to just replace that NIC (disable and purchase one to replace it, if integrated on the MoBo).

Comment: Oh yeah, when I got the computer it was running windows 11 without any network issues.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details; you may have the opportunity to change *drivers* (ie. kernel modules) by switching to an alternative kernel stack depending on the details you didn't provide, but we don't know what options you have available given no specifics as to what you're using were provided.  If it's a hardware issue though (*new failure*) that won't help, but you could test *live* systems to see if they help rather than modify kernel stacks on your *unstated* install too.  Kernel stack default are set by install media & we don't know your product/release/media

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].